# Sorting image in gridview header

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `Gridview` named `SearchGenericReport`. I want to have sorting up and down images in header of Gridview Columns. But the `GetSortColumnIndex(string strrCol)` always returns `-    value`. So I can't add images. What am I missing here?

```
public int GetSortColumnIndex(String strCol)
{
    DataTable result= Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;
    foreach (DataControlField field in result.Columns)
    {
        if (field.SortExpression == strCol)
        {
            return SearchGenericReport.Columns.IndexOf(field);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
void AddSortImage(GridViewRow headerRow)
{

    int selCol = GetSortColumnIndex(m_strSortExp);

    //if (-1 == selCol)
    //{
    //    return;
    //}

    // Create the sorting image based on the sort direction
    Image sortImage = new Image();

    if (SortDirection.Ascending == m_SortDirection)
    {
        sortImage.ImageUrl = "img/uparrow.png";
        sortImage.AlternateText = "Ascending";
    }
    else
    {
        sortImage.ImageUrl = "img/downarrow.png";
        sortImage.AlternateText = "Descending";
    }

    // Add the image to the appropriate header cell
    headerRow.Cells[selCol].Controls.Add(sortImage);

}
```

---

But when I quickWatch on gridview.Columns - its results in "enumertaion yield no results" and something. 
And Its doesnot goes into For Each loop only.. and I have modified code like this -
int GetSortColumnIndex()
        {

```
        // Iterate through the Columns collection to determine the index
        // of the column being sorted.
        foreach (DataControlField field in this.SearchGenericReport.Columns)
        {
            if (field.SortExpression == SearchGenericReport.SortExpression)
            {
                return SearchGenericReport.Columns.IndexOf(field);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
    void AddSortImage(int columnIndex,GridViewRow headerRow)
    {
        // Create the sorting image based on the sort direction
        Image sortImage = new Image();
        SortDirection direction = SearchGenericReport.SortDirection;
        if (direction == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            sortImage.ImageUrl = "img/uparrow.png";
            sortImage.AlternateText = "Ascending";
        }
        else
        {
            sortImage.ImageUrl = "img/downarrow.png";
            sortImage.AlternateText = "Descending";
        }

        // Add the image to the appropriate header cell
        headerRow.Cells[columnIndex].Controls.Add(sortImage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When multiple columns are sorted, field.[SortExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sortexpression.aspx) property contains a comma-separated list of the fields by which to sort. So you can try using the `Contains(strCol)`.

Better solution would be to split the comma separated string expression and check if it have the column `strCol`